# Нужно создать функцию countLanguages, которая принимает на вход два аргумента: объект, в котором нужно проверять наличие языков, и массив тех языков

Tags: javascript

```js
const welcomeMessages = {
  russian: 'Добро пожаловать',
  english: 'Welcome',
  french: 'Bienvenue',
  italian: 'Benvenuto',
  spanish: 'bienvenido',
  chinese: '歡迎',
  finnish: 'Tervetuloa'
};

function countLanguages(obj, propsArr) {
  // ваш код здесь`введите сюда код`
};



console.log(countLanguages(welcomeMessages, ['english', 'french', 'mandarin'])); // 2
console.log(countLanguages(welcomeMessages, ['russian', 'czech'])); // 1
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно создать функцию countLanguages, которая принимает на вход два аргумента: объект, в котором нужно проверять наличие языков, и массив тех языков, что нужно искать. Функция должна возвращать число — количество языков из переданного массива, которые есть в нашем словаре. Для прохода по массиву вызовите метод reduce. В теле его функции проверяйте наличие ключа в массиве оператором in.

Comment: Вот решение function countLanguages(obj, propsArr) {
   return propsArr.reduce((res, val) => {
  if (val in obj) {
    return res+1;
  } else {
    return res;
  }
}, 0);
}

Comment: @Вадим если это решение и вправду решает проблему указанную в вопросе, то тогда можете опубликовать его как ответ, некоторые участники могут проголосовать за него, чтобы увеличить вашу репутацию.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countLanguages(obj, propsArr) { 
return propsArr.reduce((res, val) => { 
if (val in obj) { 
return res+1;
 } else {
 return res;
 }
 }, 0); 
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
function countLanguages(obj, propsArr) {
  return propsArr.reduce(function(res, current) {
    if (current in obj) {
      res += 1;
    };
      return res;
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).